# Return customer id which didn't had any transactions in past 2 months using SQL query

Tags: mysql, transactions

I'm facing an issue while creating a sql query where I want transaction details which is older than 2 months. Can someone help me with this.

Basically, I have two table one transaction tables and one customer table.
For each customer there is record of transactions in transaction table. So, now I want a query which can retrieve all the customer_ids which didn't have any transactions in past 2 months.

**Customers**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Google |
| 2 | Facebook |
| 3 | Hooli |
| 4 | Yahoo! |

**Transaction**

| id | transaction_date | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-10 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-04-05 | 1 |
| 3 | 2022-03-09 | 1 |
| 4 | 2022-03-24 | 1 |
| 5 | 2022-02-23 | 2 |
| 6 | 2022-02-22 | 2 |
| 7 | 2022-02-21 | 2 |
| 8 | 2022-03-24 | 2 |
| 9 | 2022-03-24 | 3 |
| 10 | 2022-01-23 | 4 |
| 11 | 2022-01-22 | 4 |
| 12 | 2022-01-21 | 4 |

**Output**
Customer_id=4(since it do not have any transactions in past 2 months)

Thank you

Comment: Kindly include what you have tried and the issue you are facing.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[MySQL INTERVAL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-interval/)** in your select query. Like this:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM `transaction`
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) > MAX(transaction_date);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
customer_id  
-------------
            4
```

This query is based on the `MAX(transaction_date)` of the customer.